# How do I create a local Meteor package, with scaffolding? (Meteor 0.9.x+)

Tags: meteor

I know how to create a Meteor package by hand:

```
cd packages
mkdir username:my-package-name
cd username:my-package-name
touch package.js
```

etc...

But is there any tool that will create scaffolding for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following straight from your project directory:

```
meteor create --package username:my-package-name
```

Source: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/writingpackages